# How to build a ROS package using Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, ros

I want to build a ROS package set using Jenkins server. Here I have put the [repo](https://github.com/Alok018/iai_ringlight) link which one I want to build. If you have any idea please share with me. I have already finished the setting up the Jenkins server.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's recommended to use the ROS build farm for this; it was built for this purpose. There's a small amount of configuration, but all the steps are laid out clearly [here.](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/buildfarm_deployment)